# The following dropdown appears on my PC browser, but does not work on my phone browser

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

The code that has been linked below is working fine in Chrome on my desktop, but when displayed on my phone the "Meetings" dropdown menu does not even appear.

Please visit https://jsfiddle.net/Spleendrivel/mg3upjqh/ to see code example.

There really is not much more detail I can provide, interestingly when I separate the css and js code into the appropriate windows on jsfiddle it seems to break...

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="Width=device-Width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                background: url(images/SandyBackground.jpg) repeat
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 2400px) {
                body {
                    font-size: 2vw;
                    color: black;
                }
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
                body {
                    font-size: 1.8vw;
                    color: black;
                }
            }

            .hidden {
                display:none;
            }

            svg text {
               font-family: FontAwesome;
            }

            .icon::before {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-right: .5em;
                font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
                font-size: inherit;
                text-rendering: auto;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
                transform: translate(0, 0);
            }

            td {
                padding:0 5px 0 5px;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
         <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li class="menu-item dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="CloseAll();">Meetings</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="toggleMonMeetings();">Monday</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="toggleTueMeetings();">Tuesday</a></li>
                     <li class="menu-item "><a class="dropdown-item" onclick="toggleCommitteeMeetings();" href="#">Committee Meetings</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>

                <div id="MonMeetingsContent" style="display:none" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="100%">
                        <col style="width:9%">
                        <col style="width:9%">
                        <col style="width:30%">
                        <col style="width:35%">
                        <col style="width:13%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>MONDAY</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Where</th>
                                <th>Map Link</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr height="2" bgcolor="#222222">
                                <td colspan="5">  </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#BDBDBD" id="Font75">
                                <td style="text-align:left"><B>MON</B></td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">5:30p</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">A NEW LIGHT (D H JFT O     No Children Allowed)</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Step One Coffee House, 6719 E. 2nd Street, Suite A,  Prescott Valley</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left"><a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.579271,-112.348131">MAP</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#DEDEDE" id="Font75">
                                <td >  </td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">7:00p</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">LOST AND FOUND (D LC O)</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Safe Harbor, 520 Delano St.,  Prescott</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left"><a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.572087,-112.471348">MAP</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="4" bgcolor="#000000">
                                <td colspan="5">  </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div id="TueMeetingsContent" style="display:none" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="100%">
                        <col style="width:9%">
                        <col style="width:9%">
                        <col style="width:30%">
                        <col style="width:35%">
                        <col style="width:13%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>TUESDAY</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Where</th>
                                <th>Map Link</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr height="2" bgcolor="#222222">
                                <td colspan="5">  </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#BDBDBD" id="Font75">
                                <td style="text-align:left"><B>TUE</B></td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Noon</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">LUNAR NOONER (D JFT O)</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">635 N. 1st Street, Treehouse Learning Community Center,  Prescott</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left"><a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.552718,-112.471647">MAP</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#DEDEDE" id="Font75">
                                <td >  </td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">7:00p</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">LOST AND FOUND (D H JFT O)</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Safe Harbor, 520 Delano St.,  Prescott</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left"><a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.572087,-112.471348">MAP</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#CDCDCD" id="Font75">
                                <td >  </td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">7:30p</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">GRATITUDE TOO GROUP (D H JFT NC O)</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Step One Coffee House, 6719 E. 2nd Street, Suite A,  Prescott Valley</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left"><a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.579271,-112.348131">MAP</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="4" bgcolor="#000000">
                                <td colspan="5">  </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div id="CommitteeMeetingsContent" style="display:none" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" width="100%">
                        <col style="width:9%">
                        <col style="width:16%">
                        <col style="width:31%">
                        <col style="width:44%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>What</th>
                                <th>Where</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr height="4" bgcolor="#000000">
                                <td colspan="4">  </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#BDBDBD" id="Font75">
                                <td style="text-align:left"><b>1<sup>st</sup> SUN</b></td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">05-06-2018 12:30pm</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Activities SubCommittee</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Frozen Frannies, 104 W. Gurley St., Prescott&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.542005, -112.469079">MAP</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#DFDFDF" id="Font75">
                                <td style="text-align:left"><b>2<sup>nd</sup> SAT</b></td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">05-12-2018 12:30pm</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">H&I SubCommittee</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Step One Coffee House, 6719 E. 2nd Street, Suite B,  Prescott Valley&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.579301,-112.348046">MAP</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#BDBDBD" id="Font75">
                                <td style="text-align:left"><b>2<sup>nd</sup> SUN</b></td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">05-13-2018 10:00am</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Yavapai Area Service Committee (YASC)</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Step One Coffee House, 6719 E. 2nd Street, Suite B,  Prescott Valley&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.579301,-112.348046">MAP</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr bgcolor="#DFDFDF" id="Font75">
                                <td style="text-align:left"><b>3<sup>rd</sup> WED</b></td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">05-18-2018 5:30pm</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">PR SubCommittee</td>
                                <td style="text-align:left">Panera Bread, 3065 Gateway Blvd, Prescott&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=34.551229, -112.412528">MAP</a></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr height="4" bgcolor="#000000">
                                <td colspan="4">  </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JQuery code -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified BootStrap Code -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script>
            function toggleMonMeetings() {
             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }


            function toggleTueMeetings() {
             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }


            function toggleCommitteeMeetings() {
             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
             else
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'block';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

            }

            function CloseAll() {
             if (CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              CommitteeMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (MonMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              MonMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';

             if (TueMeetingsContent.style.display == 'block')
              TueMeetingsContent.style.display = 'none';
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because the bootstrap class [collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) is hiding the navigation bar and replaced with a button in the top right corner. Only when the button is clicked, the navigation bar will be displayed again. Your code doesn't have that button.

Since you're using Bootstrap 3 the collapse button should look like this

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

Here is a revised code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/awran5/um591sgj/

Comment: Thank you, I see that if one clicks the button, it does display the dropdown, albeit with "Meetings" in a tiny font.  But, is there any way to do this without having to first click on the button in the top right corner?

Btw, if you go to yavapaina.org you can see that the vertical bar works just fine on a phone.  I was simply trying to clean things up and create a new bar.

Comment: Yes sure, you just need to remove the `div` that have the class `collapse` .. I've modified your code a little bit including the font size to meet your needs. Check the link again.

Comment: Thank you, I will now try to expand on this by adding my header image and more dropdown selections.   For now I am accepting this final answer.